# What pages led to Conversion

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to create a "Custom Report" in Google Analytics but cannot get the dimension/metric to work. My goal is to retrieve all pages of a user that triggered an event(also a goal) on which pages before they converted(purchased - ecommerce)?

**Like this:**
**1)** User enters the main page ("/")
**2)** User goes trough 3-4 article pages (20 seconds activity triggers an event that also is a goal in GA.
**3)** User fills out form and submits (Enhanced Ecommerce - transaction)

**My Goal is to list out either:**
**1)** How many times a user triggered this particular event before purchasing
**2)** List all pages on where user triggered this particular event before purchasing.

**My Custom Report looks like this:**

[image]

But gives `0 rows` in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the filter that you are using, where you are trying to combine Hit level data with session data. Events are gathered at hit level, where as the question you ask needs to be looked at from a sessionalization perspective.

Let me describe what I believe is happening. Since a user on your website is browsing the articles page, they trigger an event called "Content viewed". Not sure how many times or the exact coding here, but let's say it triggered four times. This is then tied to the Event as a Hit to the page that it triggered on.

On the following page, the order page, they trigger the event "Order Completed" after they register, which again, the event is registered Hit level on that page. This means that on pages ABCD, they trigger the event for "Content viewed".

What you need is a segment to do this kind of analysis. A segment ties together sessions and users from Hit level data, so you can answer questions like: "Which Users have triggered "Content viewed" and then completed registration?"

Sessionalization works by creating sessions tied to a User (client ID) and what happened during that Session. A Session carries different Hits, which are then aggregated as a Unique Visitor, or User, over a number of sessions.

Hope my explanation helped!

Comment: That made everything clear @MrSponge! Thank you for explaining :)